# How to retrieve data from incremental name "table"?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

My database is saving as follows:

[image]

On another activity, I will use the "temas" values to display as tags with a horizontal RecyclerView. My problem now is that I can only retrieve the element 0 of all other elements. (In this case, the "Feminismo"). I am trying to use an incrementor inside the onBindViewHolder so it can change from 0 to 1 to 2 and on and on, but it doesn't seem to be working.

This is my ArticleActivity:

```
public class ArticlesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView txtTitle, txtAutor, txtDate;
    private RecyclerView articleTags;
    private String articleKey;
    private DatabaseReference articleRef, articleTagRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_articles);

        articleKey = getIntent().getStringExtra("articleKey");

        articleRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Artigos").child(articleKey);
        articleTagRef = articleRef.child("temas");

        initializeFields();

        articleTags = findViewById(R.id.articlesActRecyclerView);
        articleTags.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<String>()
                .setQuery(articleTagRef, String.class)
                .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<String, ArticleViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<String, ArticleViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ArticleViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull String model) {
                Toast.makeText(ArticlesActivity.this, Integer.toString(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                articleTagRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                                holder.tags.setText(dataSnapshot.child(Integer.toString(position)).getValue().toString());
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ArticleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_article_tags, viewGroup, false);
                ArticleViewHolder viewHolder = new ArticleViewHolder(view);
                return viewHolder;
            }
        };

        articleTags.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    public class ArticleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView tags;

        public ArticleViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tags = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerArticleTag);
        }

    }

    private void initializeFields() {
        txtTitle = findViewById(R.id.txtArticleActTitle);
        txtAutor = findViewById(R.id.txtArticleActAutor);
        txtDate = findViewById(R.id.txtArticleActDate);
    }
```

This is the Article xml (pretty standard one):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="6dp"
    tools:context=".ArticlesActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtArticleActTitle"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Article Title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtArticleActAutor"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtArticleActTitle"
        android:text="Article Autor"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtArticleActDate"
        android:text="Article Date"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtArticleActAutor"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/articlesActRecyclerView"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtArticleActDate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone suggest how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some changes to the Recycler methods, the new one:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Tags>()
                .setQuery(articleTagRef, Tags.class)
                .build();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Tags, ArticleViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Tags, ArticleViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ArticleViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull Tags model) {
                String tagKey = getRef(position).getKey();
                articleTagRef.child(tagKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("tagName")) {
                                String tagName = dataSnapshot.child("tagName").getValue().toString();
                                holder.tags.setTextSize(20);
                                holder.tags.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
                                holder.tags.setText(tagName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ArticleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_article_tags, viewGroup, false);
                ArticleViewHolder viewHolder = new ArticleViewHolder(view);
                return viewHolder;
            }
        };
        articleTags.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }
```

I've created too a Tags class:

```
public class Tags {
    private String tagName;

    public Tags() {
    }

    public Tags(String tagName) {
        this.tagName = tagName;
    }

    public String getTagName() {
        return tagName;
    }

    public void setTagName(String tagName) {
        this.tagName = tagName;
    }
}
```

Changed too the `recycler_article_tags.xml` to `wrap_content` on the `RelativeLayout` and on the `TextView`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/buttons"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerArticleTag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally, the database is now like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the child nodes of a snapshot with `DataSnapshot.getChildren()`:

```
articleRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Artigos").child(articleKey);
articleTagRef = articleRef.child("temas");

articleTagRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(childSnapshot.getKey()); // prints 0, 1, etc
            System.out.println(childSnapshot.getValue(String.class)); // prints "Feminismo", "Racismo", etc
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

Comment: And how could I set it using a horizontal RecyclerView Frank? I got the data now, but it still needs to be displayed horizontally